# Find files that have been accessed after they were created

Tags: linux

With the find command it is easy to find files that have been modified or accessed within a given period.

When a file is created, the acesss time is the same as the modify time. But as soon it is accessed (read), the access time changes, but the modify time does not.

I need to find files that been accessed at all, ie. files which have access time newer than modify time.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I % find -path % -anewer %
```

Comment: This works great! Can you explain how it works?

Comment: Btw, in the meantime I constructed this ugly command:

find . -exec sh -c "stat {} | awk --re-interval '/File:/ {file=\$2} /(Access|Modify): [0-9]{4}/ {if(\$1==\"Access:\")access=\$3; else modify=\$3} END {if(access!=modify) print file}'" \;

Comment: @marlar: It finds all files then sends them via `xargs` through another `find` which compares the access time to its own modified time. The `-I %` acts like a variable which holds the filename and is used twice in the second find command. If there are a lot of files it could be slow since it goes through all of them twice.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this in a single traversal with GNU find (let alone POSIX find). It's a simple one-liner with Perl's `File::Find`:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find({wanted => sub {print "$File::Find::name\n" if -f && -M _ > -A _}}, @ARGV);' .
```

Make sure that your files are mounted without the `noatime` or `relatime` option — recent Linux distributions tend to use it by default.